# How to make condition in Angular (IONIC)?

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

Im trying to learn Andgular and IONIC framework. But now I dont know how to make condition like this:

```
    if (price = false) {
echo 'No price';
}
```

Now I have this code in IONIC

```
<h2 style="font-size:15px;margin:0 0 4px">{{item.name}}</h2>
<h3 style="color:red;" *ngIf="!item.special;"> {{item.price}}</h3>
<h3 color="primary" *ngIf="item.special"><del>{{item.price}}</del></h3>
<h3 color="danger" *ngIf="item.special"> {{item.special}}</h3>
<p style="margin:3px 0 6px">{{item.description}}</p>
```

Comment: what you want to do exactly? You want to check this condition in html file or ts?

Comment: In HTML. Now I have price. But I'd like to see "No price" if server says "false". Now I see false. I want to see "No price". Im tring to make condition

Comment: how server says "false" and where you see false? In html? In which line?

Comment: Note that `if (price = false)` is always false.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just show info about no price in your html you should use:

```
<h3 *ngIf="!item.price">No price</h3>
```

Comment: No, I have price. But when server says false, so there should be text "No price".

Comment: but where this false come from? I thought that 'no price' should be visible if the price is not set

Answer (score 1):

Use **angular** way with **ternary operator.**

```
<h3>{{!item.price ?'No price':item.price}}</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="item.price">
    No price
</ng-container>
```

It's better because ng-container doesn't exists in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check in .ts file,

```
     if(!price){
       console.log("false")
     }
```

or

```
     if(price==false){
       console.log("false)
     }
```

if you want to check in HTML file,

```
     <h3 *ngIf="!price">{{ price }}</h3>
```